# Trying to create 2GP package version - getting "Could not infer a metadata type"

Tags: lightning-web-components, rest-api, 2gp, csp

Am starting to build Lightning Web Components that will need to call an external API. Looks like I need to add **CSP Trusted Sites** and **Remote Site Settings**. So I created folders in /force-app/main/default called **cspTrustedSites** and **remoteSiteSettings**. Within them, I followed the metadata documentation.

Here's MyTrustedSites.cspTrustedSite:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CspTrustedSite xmlns="https://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <context>All</context>
  <description>For API calls, styles, fonts, media, and images</description>
  <developerName>MyTrustedSites</developerName>
  <endpointUrl>https://*.example.com</endpointUrl>
  <isActive>true</isActive>
  <isApplicableToConnectSrc>true</isApplicableToConnectSrc>
  <isApplicableToFontSrc>true</isApplicableToFontSrc>
  <isApplicableToFrameSrc>true</isApplicableToFrameSrc>
  <isApplicableToImgSrc>true</isApplicableToImgSrc>
  <isApplicableToMediaSrc>true</isApplicableToMediaSrc>
  <isApplicableToStyleSrc>true</isApplicableToStyleSrc>
  <masterLabel>My Trusted Sites</masterLabel>
  <namespacePrefix>sumthin</namespacePrefix>
</CspTrustedSite>
```

When I issue `sfdx package:version:create -p 0Ho... --installation-key-bypass -b 2gp-internal --code-coverage`, I get this error:

> Error (1): Component conversion failed:
> /var/folders/qd/REDACTED/T/0Ho...-REDACTED/md-files/cspTrustedSites/MyTrustedSites.cspTrustedSit:
> Could not infer a metadata type

Note: the error message omits the final "e" in the file extension but it's there. Seems to be an sfdx bug.

If I move the cspTrustedSites and remoteSiteSettings folders out of my project temporarily, I can create the package version.

```bash
sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/7.187.1 darwin-arm64 node-v18.14.0
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is the filename really `MyTrustedSites.cspTrustedSit`? There's a terminal `e` missing.

Comment: Hey... thanks for jumping in. It actually ends in an "e". I tried shortening the name (a.cspTrustedSite) but that didn't change the way the error is displayed. I think it might be a red herring to the true problem. Have you ever bundled cspTrustedSites or remoteSiteSettings in a 2GP? Seems like it was possible in 1GPs.

Comment: I have not. Can you reproduce the same error with a minimal package that _only_ contains your cspTrustedSites? That might be a reportable bug for the SFDX GitHub repo. You're on the latest CLI version?

Comment: Yup. It is reproducible just with the cspTrustedSites and nothing else. Using sfdx-cli/7.187.1 darwin-arm64 node-v18.14.0 (latest/greatest). According to the docs for API v56, this metadata should be supported both for 1GP and 2GP... https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/56

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full name of my metadata file was `MyTrustedSites.cspTrustedSite`. It needed to be `MyTrustedSites.cspTrustedSite-meta.xml`.

My mistake was using the file created by `sf retrieve metadata` without changing the name. Not sure why it doesn't add `-meta.xml` by default but...